# Map latitude and lang differs for same point in openlayer?

Tags: leaflet, mapping, gis, openstreetmap, openlayers-3

As openstreetmap provides us with the base word map but same point for example word map will be not one , it will be replicated but as i take lat long from one map to another i am getting different lat,long for same point.

1. How to take openstreet map with one world view.
2. How to get same lat ,long for same point.
3. As i am using openlayer at client side.

Comment: share your code to get help this information is minimal

Comment: Sounds like a projection error. You should definitely provide code!